# Why I'm getting wrong int-float comparison result?

Tags: c++

Why I'm getting output as `Yes` though 9.58 is not less than 9.58 or Is there anything wrong with this `If` condition?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   float x = 9.58;

   if (x < 9.58)
   {
      std::cout << "Yes" << '\n';
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: try `std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << x << '\n';`

Comment: I suggest you print the value of `x`.

Comment: Also remember that in the expression `x < 9.58` the variable `x` is a single precision `float`, while `9.58` is a *double* precision floating point value (in essence a `double` value).

Comment: I don't see an `int` anywhere in this code. (Well, `return (0);`, but that doesn't seem relevant.)

Comment: `9.58` is a **double**.  Maybe you wanted `9.58f` which is a **float**?

Comment: Or maybe  `double x`.

Comment: Incidentally, that is the 100 m world record.